# Button click not duplicate?

Tags: javascript

I've created the css html on my calculator. I am having a problem writing js code for point button. I do not want to write anymore, after clicking the button once. What should I do? How to write function? here is the sample code:

```
<html>

<head>

<title></title>
<script language="javascript">

function nok(){  


    value = document.getElementById("rakamkutusu").value + '.';


    document.getElementById("rakamkutusu").value = value;


}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<tr>
    <input type='Text' class="deneme" id="rakamkutusu" name="rakam" size="70" value='0'></th>
</tr>
<tr>
   <th><input name="btnNOKTA" type="Button" class="butonlar"id="nokta" value=" . " onclick="nok()"></th>
</tr>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should probably use a `if` to check if you've yet put a dot in your current number. See [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else).

Comment: Maybe you're looking for the `.one()` function? Without seeing your sample code, it's difficult to offer more advice, though.

Comment: `"I do not want to write anymore"`. Perhaps, you'd like to write a little more in your question?

Comment: Please provide more info., also some code will be not bad addition

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a homework assessment, so i'll give you a hint:

What you want, is to add an `event listener` to an element.

You could write a specific listener for every button
or just one that figures out what to do based on the button that triggered it.

update :

your function is a good place to start.
You can add a parameter to it to figure out which button was used to call it.

like this:

```
function HandleItemClicked(sender)
{
   //now do something with sender
}
```

In order to get the element that was clicked in sender, you would do something like this:

```
<div id="someElement1" onclick="HandleItemClicked(this)">1</div>
<div id="someElement2" onclick="HandleItemClicked(this)">2</div>
```

Comment: Hi Samet, Welcome to StackOverflow.
Please but that source code in the question, and format it, this is a pain to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function nok(){  
    value = document.getElementById("rakamkutusu").value + '.';
    document.getElementById("rakamkutusu").value = value;
}
</script>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MuhammadHani/646GK/)